# Is @DocumentId required for Hibernate Search?

Tags: hibernate, indexing, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search and the documentation and books say I need @DocumentId on the id field so that Hibernate Search can know how to map the index to the objects.

My code appears to be working fine without the @DocumentId anywhere in my code. Did Hibernate Search become smart enough to figure out that @Id field is a great default? Are there problems this will cause that are not obvious?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@DocumentId` is required if you are using the old-school style of mapping your entities with `.hbm.xml` files.  If you are use that mapping approach and neglect to annotate a document id, then at startup you will see an exception like this:

```
org.hibernate.search.SearchException: No document id in: com.mypackage.MyEntity
```

However, if you are using annotations and have annotated a primary key with `@Id`, then you do not have to use `@DocumentId`.

To be more precise, the Hibernate Search documentation says that `@DocumentId` is optional when using ***JPA*** annotations.  So perhaps you would still need to use `@DocumentId` if you are using Hibernate 3.x-style annotations... I've never tested this.

Either way, Hibernate 4.x deprecates its own mapping annotations in favor of JPA-style annotations, ***even if*** you are using Hibernate's `Session` rather than JPA's `EntityManager` for your queries.  So in a nutshell:  you need to use `@DocumentId` if you are using XML-style mappings... whereas it's optional if you're using annotations, because at this point you should be using JPA-style annotations anyway.

Comment: I thought this was the case but I couldn't find it in the docs. Thanks!