# Struts 2 property tag can't access abstract parent class member

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I'm having problems accessing a property via struts. I was wondering if anyone who's more experienced with struts would be able to give me a few pointers.

The java classes are roughly set up like this:

```
public abstract class parent{
    protected Integer id;

    public Integer getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
}

public class child extends parent{
    // stuff
}
```

The child is a list in an action class with getter set up:

```
private List<child> childList;
```

This is my code in the front end, attempting to grab the `id` property:

```
<s:iterator value="childList" status="cStatus">
    <s:property value='id' />
</s:iterator>
```

However, nothing shows up. I've grabbed other members from the child class, so I'm assuming there's an issue with the parent member I'm grabbing being in an abstract class?

**UPDATE**

I've attempted to grab another property in the abstract class in the `jsp` and it works fine. The other property I grabbed is `creationDate`. I've also added breakpoints to the `id` getter and it's being accessed fine and returning non-null values. Here is a more detailed implementation of the parent with `hibernate` annotations included:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class parent{
    protected Integer id;
    protected Date creationDate;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @DocumentId
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    protected void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(updatable=false, nullable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return this.creationDate;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `Child` an action class? Are you using JSON result type?

Comment: @nmenego `Child` isn't the action class. I'm not sure what you mean by JSON result type? All I'm trying to do is display the property in the HTML.

Comment: Your shown code looks fine. Are you sure `id` is being set?

Comment: What happens if you access an other property of the abstract parent and/or child class? Are they working as expeted?

Comment: Hello @AleksandrM , I've added a break point to the `id`'s getter and it seems to be returning values properly. I'll be updating the question with a few more findings in a mo.

Comment: Hi @BetaRide , I've attempted to grab another property from the abstract parent (`creationDate`, Date object) and it actually works. I'm puzzled how `id` is different.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in

```
private List<child> childList;
```

it requires

```
private List<child> childList = new ArrayList<>();
public List<child> getChildList(){
  return childList;
}
```

in JSP

```
<s:iterator value="childList" status="cStatus">
    <s:property value="id" />
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: @d_ominic And what about changing single quotas to double?

Comment: JSP attributes can be single or double quoted. If there wasn't a getter it would be a different error.

Comment: @DaveNewton It's good that you mentioned it, but better to use double quotas for attribute value and single quota for characters inside. Many IDEs, including IntelliJ IDEA, JSP editors red mark values with nested quotas either single or double inside the attribute value. Anyway OGNL access inherited properties the same way as not inherited. It's *very* unclear what OP is asking.

Comment: @d_ominic May be `id` property not initialized, are you sure you have set non-null the value to it and action returns dispatcher result to render JSP?

Comment: Hi @RomanC , first off, thanks for your input. I've added breakpoints to the getter and it's actually being called and returning non-null values just fine. So I don't think the issue is with struts accessing the property. I've updated the question text with a few more findings.

Comment: Looks like you have, first off, with `@DocumentId` see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12698152/573032).